# how to resolve video URL from Instagram page using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

with the new policy from Instagram, they changed the way that the URL appears in the source code page so the original url dosen't look plain anymore
video_url Appears like

> video_url":"https://instagram.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/248775760_413698173819615_512496183529317258_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=103\u0026_nc_ohc=R95u_rTZD5oAX-hZX34\u0026edm=AABBvjUBAAAA\u0026ccb=7-4\u0026oe=618206D6\u0026oh=1a20272f818c87943def9daae413a40e\u0026_nc_sid=83d603">>

so how to convert this link into the original link using python?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'video_url":"https://instagram.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/248775760_413698173819615_512496183529317258_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=103\u0026_nc_ohc=R95u_rTZD5oAX-hZX34\u0026edm=AABBvjUBAAAA\u0026ccb=7-4\u0026oe=618206D6\u0026oh=1a20272f818c87943def9daae413a40e\u0026_nc_sid=83d603">>'
url = a.split('"')[2]
```

Comment: it worked for me also  this one worked                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                               >downloadFile ="url"

print(downloadFile.replace("\u0026","&"))>